# How do I set up two versions of PHP with a single Apache server?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I have a major problem.. I've been asked to manage a web application that's from a dinosaur era.. I think they used 5.2 or lesser. Tried to run their application in my setup which i am using PHP 5.3. Too many deprecated errors. So now I'm in a tight situation to uninstall my lamp to run this application.

**Few questions:**

1. If I set up two versions of PHP, will my other applications still run smoothly?
2. Is having two versions of PHP a good idea? I'm pretty sure it will have some flaws.
3. If I indeed install different versions of PHP will it be compatible with my Apache and MySQL, or will I need to install other software as well?
4. How do I set this all up?

Hope anyone can help me here...

Comment: PHP 5.2 is the dinosaur era?

Comment: actually what I meants was the system is using codeigniter mvc version 1.7.0 which now its in 2.0.3. For more info the application is using php 5.2.10 but I'm using 5.3. I guess my last resort is using cgi but don't know how to set that up.

Comment: The only way I know is effectively to run PHP in cgi and/org fastcgi mode. Some distribution may facilitate the job (gentoo maybe?). You shoudl ask for such support on servfault instead of stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2, is a pretty decent version of PHP. Anyway, if you need to upgrade, why don't you just turn off the deprecation warnings? They shouldn't be on in production anyway, they are useful only for your development.

Find the error_reporting line in your php.ini and change as:

```
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE;
```

Or at runtime:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
```

If you really want to install two versions of PHP, which I don't recommend you, you can bind them to different extensions. You can run only one version as module, while other versions can run as CGI.

Comment: tried that., but it didn't ignore those errors. set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated others are &=. Tried changing the codes php 5.3 will accept and it fix those errors but still can't run the application. T_T.

Answer (score 0):

Only one version of the PHP module can be loaded into Apache at a time. You'll have to pick which one that is.

Comment: What you say is true, but you can run more than one PHP version if only one runs as module and others run as CGI. I won't recommend it, though.